# How do they acquire this cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

How do they acquire the CDF in this problem?  I don't even see  $f_{X}$ and its integral anywhere.  They simply jump straight to the answer.  Can someone enlighten me?  TIA!

[image: cdf]

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of equations for $F_Y$ (and it really is a *set* of equations, because there are two $=$ signs between the formulas) gives you two options of how to calculate $F_Y$.
One option is to use the formula from the right side of the second equation:
$$ F_Y(y) = \int_{\{x\mid g(x) \leq y\}} f_X(x)\,dx. $$
But the other option is to just use the first equation:
$$ F_Y(y) = P(g(X) \leq y). $$

In example 4.1, the text uses the first equation:
$$ F_Y(y) = P(\sqrt X \leq y). $$
Then we observe that $X$ is guaranteed to be non-negative
(since its support is $[0,1]$, and a good thing too because otherwise $\sqrt X$ could be undefined), so $\sqrt X \leq y$ if and only if $X \leq y^2.$
That is, the event "$\sqrt X \leq y$" is the exact same event as the event
"$X \leq y^2$". Therefore
$$ P(\sqrt X \leq y) = P(X \leq y^2). $$

Finally, you *could* evaluate $P(X \leq y^2)$ by integrating $f_X(x) = 0$
from $x=-\infty$ to $x=0$ and $f_X(x) = 1$ from $x=0$ to $x=y^2.$
But do you really need to write out the integral every time when some one gives you a variable, in this case $X$, with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, and some number $z$, and asks you what is the probability $P(X \leq z)$?
The author didn't think so, so they didn't write the integral.
The probability is always $P(X \leq z) = z$ if $z \in [0,1].$
And in this case $z = y^2.$

Comment: How do you know integration interval of $f_X(x)$ is from $x=0$ to $x=y^2$?

Comment: Technically you also integrate $f_X(x)$ from $-\infty$ to $0$, but that part always comes to zero for a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ so I left it out of the first version of the answer.

Comment: For the second reasoning, are you saying if $z \in [0,1]$, and $X$ is uniform in $[0,1]$ then $P(X \leq z) = z$?

Comment: Yes, that's it. You can prove it with an integral if you want, but you only need to do that once.

Comment: By definition of CDF, that is clear now.  Thank you so much!!!  Are you a professor, btw?